# Python tkinter scope labels not displaying

Tags: python, tkinter

Im new to python and am currently running into a scope problem I believe. 
I am trying to make a window pop up with a function call. However I do think that this may be accomplished better with a class. Like I said I am a beginner. Both Syntax fixes as well as better programming methods are welcome. My code is as follows

```
from tkinter import *

def showProdScreen():
  root = Tk()
  root.title("Production")
  count = 0
  countStr = StringVar()

  countStr.set("0");

  def countUp():
    nonlocal count
    nonlocal countStr
    print(countStr.get())
    count = count + 1
    countStr.set(count)


  up = Button(root, text = "AddCnt", command = countUp, width = 15, font = ("Curier", 16))

  countl = Label(root, text = "Count", relief = RAISED, font = ("Curier", 20), width = 10)
  countVal = Label(root, textvariable = countStr, relief = RAISED, font = ("Curier", 20), width = 10)


  countVal.pack();
  countl.pack();
  up.pack()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As soon as `showProdScreen()` exits, there are no remaining references to `runtime`, so the var gets deleted (resulting in the label that was displaying to becoming blank).  Your `setRuntime()` function is useless as shown, since nothing will ever be able to call it; if you had saved a reference to it somewhere for later use, that would also keep a reference to `runtime` alive.

Comment: @jasonharper but I can still print out the value of the StringVar() how would i put this in a class

Comment: Also why the -1? my question was clear it has a definite answer? it may be a bit of a beginner question but its just discouraging for a random -1 for no reason

Comment: The downvote is most likely due to this question being a "Bad" question as far as Stack Overflow guidelines are concerned. SO is not your typical QA site. Here we answer specific code problems so your questions should follow the guidelines here: [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Its can be summed up like this. Create the smallest possible example to reproduce the problem. Other code is unnecessary and unwanted.

Comment: @Mike-SMT This is closer to the original quesstion is that a more proper question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a list of things you should work on.

1. You really should do `import tkinter as tk` and then use `tk.` prefix when working with tkinter. This will prevent mistakenly overtiring built in methods.
2. Python PEP8 says to use 4 spaces per indention so instead of 2 spaces start using 4.
3. I do not believe it is common for people to use functions inside of functions and I imagine this is for a good reason.
4. I have never seen the use of `nonlocal` (only 2 years using Python at this point) so this is new to me. Normally one would use `global` when dealing with non-class function in tkinter. On that note you probably should use class to avoid `global`.
5. When tracking a counter you should use one of the number variables. For example here we can use `IntVar()` and then we do not need to track with a counter.

Here are some examples with your code cleaned up, a non-OOP example and a class example.

What you are doing in your updated question is IMO a strange way to build a GUI. Here is your example cleaned up and working:

```
from tkinter import *

def showProdScreen():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Production")
    count = 0
    countStr = StringVar()
    countStr.set("0");

    def countUp():
        nonlocal count
        nonlocal countStr
        print(countStr.get())
        count = count + 1
        countStr.set(count)

    Button(root, text="AddCnt", command=countUp, width=15, font=("Curier", 16)).pack()
    Label(root, text="Count", relief=RAISED, font=("Curier", 20), width=10).pack()
    Label(root, textvariable=countStr, relief=RAISED, font=("Curier", 20), width=10).pack()

    root.mainloop()

showProdScreen()
```

That said I am not sure why you are building it this way with a function inside of a function.

When building in a non-OOP way you should use global and function here.
For a non-OOP example I would do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Production")
count_str = tk.IntVar()
count_str.set(0)

def countUp():
    global count_str
    count_str.set(count_str.get() + 1)

tk.Label(root, textvariable=count_str, relief="raised", font=("Curier", 20), width=10).pack()
tk.Label(root, text="Count", relief="raised", font=("Curier", 20), width=10).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="AddCnt", command=countUp, width=15, font=("Curier", 16)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

For a class example I would do this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Production")
        self.count_str = tk.IntVar()
        self.count_str.set(0)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.count_str, relief="raised", font=("Curier", 20), width=10).pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Count", relief="raised", font=("Curier", 20), width=10).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="AddCnt", command=self.count_up, width=15, font=("Curier", 16)).pack()

    def count_up(self):
        self.count_str.set(self.count_str.get() + 1)

Example().mainloop()
```

Comment: The working code is at https://github.com/calebbaker194/ProductionMonitor Im sure i made 100 more mistakes, Thanks for taking the extra time to explain some good practices. also "nonlocal" is used only in the case of nested functions. its the middle ground between global and local.